# R extension in C: how to link a struct to a SEXP pointer?

Tags: r, c, garbage-collection

I'm currently writing a [C extension for R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html). I would like to create a `struct` linked to an existing SEXP pointer. For example:

```
struct MyData {
    SEXP exp;
    int i;
}

SEXP create(SEXP p1)
{
    struct MyData p* = malloc(sizeof(MyData));
    p->exp =  p1;
    p->i = 1234;
    SEXP ext = PROTECT(R_MakeExternalPtr(p, R_NilValue,R_NilValue));
    R_RegisterCFinalizerEx(ext,myFinalizer, TRUE);
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return ext;
}

void myFinalizer(SEXP x)
{
    void * p = R_ExternalPtrAddr(handle);
    free(p);
}
```

How to correctly handle the `p->exp` pointer? How to tell the garbage manager that I'm using a SEXP data? How should I protect/unprotect this SEXP data?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I answered my problem instead of wrapping a

```
struct MyData {
    SEXP exp;
    int i;
}
```

I create a vector:

```
SEXP ext = PROTECT(allocVector(VECSXP, 2));nprotect++;
SET_VECTOR_ELT(ext, 0, exp);
SET_VECTOR_ELT(ext, 1, sexpI);
```

and `ext` **is** my object and I let the R garbage manager to manage it. But the structure is not opaque and the user can modifiy it.